# Detect rotation angle and rotate final video using ffmpeg version 2.8

Tags: ffmpeg

I used to work on ffmpeg 2.2 until now and was detecting rotation angle of video uploaded from android / iPhone mobiles and rotate the resulting video so that it run perfectly on a correct angle.

But since I have updated the ffmpeg to version 2.8 I am getting this rotation problem. My queries are not rotating the videos as they were earlier.

Here'r the commands I was using:

To check rotation angle:

```
ffprobe -of json -show_streams {$input} | grep rotate
```

below is my **final command** to convert a video to mp4

```
"ffmpeg -i {$input} -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -vb 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf 'scale=-1:480 ".fix_video_orientation($input)."' -threads 0 -ab 64k -s {$resolution}  -movflags faststart -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 {$output}";
```

"fix_video_orientation" function is given below. It detect the angle of rotation of the initial video and output optimal option for rotating the final video.

```
function fix_video_orientation($input){

$return= ", transpose=1 ";

$dd= exec("ffprobe -of json -show_streams  {$input}   | grep rotate");

if(!empty($dd)){

$dd=explode(":",$dd);
$rotate=str_replace(",","",str_replace('"',"",$dd[1]));

if($rotate=="90")return $return;

else if ($rotate=="180") return ", transpose=2,transpose=2 ";

else if($rotate == "270") return ", transpose=2 ";
}
```

Currently above script is supporting "flv","avi","mp4","mkv","mpg","wmv","asf","webm","mov","3gp","3gpp" extensions, also the script is supporting the resulting .mp4 file to play on all browsers and devices.

Now the ffprobe command is not returning rotation angle and so a portrait video if uploaded from iphone is showing as landscape on the website.

Output console of ffprobe command:

```
ffprobe version N-77455-g4707497 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
libavutil 55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
libavcodec 57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
libavformat 57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
libavdevice 57. 0.100 / 57. 0.100
libavfilter 6. 21.101 / 6. 21.101
libavresample 3. 0. 0 / 3. 0. 0
libswscale 4. 0.100 / 4. 0.100
libswresample 2. 0.101 / 2. 0.101
libpostproc 54. 0.100 / 54. 0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/standard/PORTRAIT.m4v':
Metadata:
major_brand : qt

minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: qt

creation_time : 2016-02-03 05:25:18
com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 4S
com.apple.quicktime.software: 9.2.1
com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2016-02-03T10:52:11+0530
Duration: 00:00:03.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7910 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2016-02-03 05:25:18
handler_name : Core Media Data Handler
Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 7832 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2016-02-03 05:25:18
handler_name : Core Media Data Handler
encoder : H.264
Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2016-02-03 05:25:18
handler_name : Core Media Data Handler
Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2016-02-03 05:25:18
handler_name : Core Media Data Handler
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
```

If latest version of ffmpeg (2.8) is used to auto rotate the video, can you please suggest me what option I need to add or remove from my **final command**.

Comment: Recent versions of ffmpeg automatically rotate video and strip the rotation tag. Also, paste your full console output.

Comment: @Mulvya I have added the query as well as its console output above.

Comment: Also I tried to install a latest version of ffmpeg on my localhost (linux mint) but it too install "ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
". Where as when I checked online latest version is 2.8.5. How can I install the latest version? Or How to upgrade my current version of ffmpeg library?

Comment: Try https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux

Comment: @Mulvya. I have updated my ffmpeg to 2.8 version can you please tell me how to detect angle of video uploaded and rotate them so that they run well.   Such that if user upload a portrait video, we rotate the final video run in portrait instead of landscape.

Comment: Let me update my question to give you an idea for what's going on.

Comment: Can you please look at the updated question above, I have tried to mention whats happening on my server.

Comment: Use just `-vf 'scale=-1:480'` (so remove the fix.. function)

Comment: let me run more tests

Comment: Great its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try asking this in superuser.com.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -an out.mp4
```

Source:
https://superuser.com/questions/1092951/how-to-delete-a-single-metadata-item-from-an-mp4-file